# Blender destroys sculpt whenever saving

Tags: sculpting

I've been working on this sculpt for over two hours now and all I am doing right now is I have disabled DynTopo to move the mouth a bit more inwards. It works like a charm. After that I hit ctrl+S to save. Then it suddenly reverts to the state before I have moved the mouth inwards and when I hit ctrl+Z that abomination happens you see in the second screenshot. A bit help in that would be highly appreciated, I would hate to loose the work. If I Ctrl-Z further the artifacts just keep getting worse. [image: Image 1 after editing, before saving]

[image: After saving and Ctrl+Z once]

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit > preferences.

on interface tab find and enable "developer extras"

now go to experimental tab and enable undo legacy
[image]

your undoes will become slower but more accurate.
consider sending a bug report.
Here is how:
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports